# multiple hue in same kdeplot

Tags: python, seaborn

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

TRIALS = int(10e3)
RATE_A = 0.65
RATE_B = 0.66
SIMS = int(4e3)

np.random.seed(42)

df_sim = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": np.random.binomial(TRIALS, RATE_A, SIMS) / TRIALS,
        "B": np.random.binomial(TRIALS, RATE_B, SIMS) / TRIALS,
    }
)

df_sim = df_sim.with_columns(
    (pl.col("B") - pl.col("A")).alias("treat_B")
    )

df_melt = df_sim.melt(
    value_vars=["A", "B", "treat_B"], 
    variable_name='distribution', 
    value_name='mean')

df_melt = df_melt.with_columns(
    (pl.when(df_melt['mean'] > 0) # & df_melt['distribution'] == 'treat_B')
        .then(pl.lit("pos"))
        .otherwise(pl.lit("neg"))
        .alias('direction')
    )
)

sb.set(style="whitegrid")
sb.set(font_scale=2)

dens_all = sb.kdeplot(
  data=df_melt.filter(pl.col("distribution")=='treat_B'), 
  x="mean", 
  #hue="direction", 
  fill=True, 
  common_norm=False, 
  alpha=.5)

dens_all.set_xlabel("Simulated Sample Means for treat_B")

dens_all.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(1, 0))
```

[image]

I would like to display this single density plot with all density left of 0 as red and all density right of 0 as blue. However if I add an argument for `hue` I get two separate density plots.

How can I control fill color while maintaining a single density plot?

[image]

common_norm and multiple args bring me closer, but not to the direct split I want.

```
dens_all = sb.kdeplot(
  data=df_melt.filter(pl.col("distribution")=='treat_B'), 
  x="mean", 
  hue="direction", 
  fill=True, 
  common_norm=True, 
  multiple='stack',
  alpha=.5)

dens_all.set_xticks(np.arange(-0.02, 0.04, 0.01))
dens_all.set_title('4e3 Simulated Samples for treat_B')
dens_all.set_xlabel("Simulated Sample Means for treat_B")

dens_all.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(1, 0))

plt.axvline(0, color='red')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sns.kdeplot(..., fill=False)` a lineplot is generated of which you can extract the coordinates.  These coordinates can be used as input to `ax.fill_between()`.

Here is how the code could look like:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

TRIALS = int(10e3)
RATE_A = 0.65
RATE_B = 0.66
SIMS = int(4e3)

np.random.seed(42)

df_sim = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.binomial(TRIALS, RATE_A, SIMS) / TRIALS,
                       "B": np.random.binomial(TRIALS, RATE_B, SIMS) / TRIALS})

df_sim["treat_B"] = df_sim["B"] - df_sim["A"]
df_sim["direction"] = np.where(df_sim["treat_B"] > 0, "pos", "neg")

sns.set_style("whitegrid")

ax = sns.kdeplot(data=df_sim, x="treat_B", fill=False)
ax.set_xlabel("Simulated Sample Means for treat_B")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(1, 0))

x, y = ax.get_lines()[0].get_data() # extract the coordinates of the kde curve

i0 = np.argmin(np.abs(x)) # index of x value closest to zero
ax.fill_between(x[:i0 + 1], y[:i0 + 1], color="crimson", alpha=0.5)
ax.fill_between(x[i0:], y[i0:], color="skyblue", alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image: kdeplot with two colors]